# How to make desktop launcher execute as program through code in MonoDevelop

Tags: command-line, permissions, launcher, chmod, monodevelop

I'm creating a program in MonoDevelop that creates a desktop launcher. It writes the launcher, but it's not executable. I've tried using a `chmod 755 $AppPath` command from the terminal, but I must be passing the arguments incorrectly because I continue to get a `chmod command not found` error. System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity commands throw errors of `not supported on platform (ubuntu 16.04 i386)`.

> Error when getting information for file '/home/mrme60/Projects/ChromeApp/bin/Debug/chmod 755 /home/mrme60/Desktop/CodeProject.desktop': No such file or directory Process.Start ("chmod 755 " + app);

I've tried googling this with no luck.

Comment: Please show the code. Also please copy the error from the MonoDevelop console into the question if there is one.

Comment: //Error when getting information for file  '/home/mrme60/Projects/ChromeApp/bin/Debug/chmod 755 /home/mrme60/Desktop/CodeProject.desktop': No such file or directory
Process.Start ("chmod 755 " + app);

Comment: Process.Start("chmod", "755 " + app); fixed it. i forgot that 755 and the path are arguments of chmod

Answer (score -1):

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("chmod", "755 " + app);
Process.Start(psi);